# Why does this test for firebase security rule fails?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection `UserActivity`, where each `docId` is the id of the user. Under different `docId`s I have subcollection `profileVisit` where I want to put some data My firebase rule, should allow **only** create operation. That is, user can create subcollection under `Useractivity/{userId}/profileVisit` only if they are logged in and they own this resource. So my firebase rule is the following:

```
match /UsersActivity/{userId} {
      match /profileVisit {
        allow create: if userIsAuthenticated() && userOwnsResource(userId);
      }
    }

function userIsAuthenticated () {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function userOwnsResource (userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId
    }
```

That is, thefollowing operation should be allowed:

```
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("UserActivity")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("profileVisit")
      .add({
        data: "some data",
      });
```

The test which I wrote is the following:

```
it("Users can create subcollection profileVisit under their own UsersActivity document if they are signed in", async () => {
    const db = getFirestore(auth);
    const userDoc = db
      .collection("UsersActivity")
      .doc(myId)
      .collection("profileVisit");
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(userDoc.add({ data: "data" }));
  });
```

This test fails with: `FirebaseError: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: false for 'create'`

Can someone explain to me why does my test fail? Have I written my rule correctly or is it the test written in the wrong way?

***EDIT***

Seems that changing the rule to:

```
match /UsersActivity/{userId} {
          match /profileVisit/{id} {
            allow create: if userIsAuthenticated() && userOwnsResource(userId);
          }
        }
```

allows my test to pass. That is I changed `match /profileVisit` to `match /profileVisit/{id} {` Can someone explain me why there is a difference and why I need to add `{id}` in the end?

Comment: What is `.uid` in the code snippet? How is that initialized?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `.doc(uid)`. it is just `uid`, I posted it for illustration purposes. I think I found my "mistake"... The second, nested rule should be `match /profileVisit/{id} `, that is I need to add `{id}` even though I don't use it in the rule?

Comment: You're on to something. Look into it and let us know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered yourself in your edit, this doesn't do anything:

```
match /UsersActivity/{userId} {
  match /profileVisit {
    allow create: if userIsAuthenticated() && userOwnsResource(userId);
  }
}
```

The `match /profileVisit` matches the `profileVisit` collection, but no documents in that, so it's a noop.

To make it match any document, use:

```
match /UsersActivity/{userId} {
  match /profileVisit/{docId} {
    allow create: if userIsAuthenticated() && userOwnsResource(userId);
  }
}
```